# How to document recursive data structures in response with Spring REST Docs

Tags: spring-restdocs

I have a question with regards to Spring Restdocs. One of the rest calls I want to document returns a recursive data structure, with different types children: leaf and subtree. Leaf and subtrees have different attributes. For example:

```
{
    "id": "$",
    "left": {
        "id": "l",
        "left": {
            "id": "l1",
            "type": "leaf",
            "value": "Leaf 1"
        },
        "right": {
            "id": "l2",
            "type": "leaf",
            "value": "Leaf 2"
        },
        "type": "subtree"
    },
    "right": {
        "id": "l3",
        "type": "leaf",
        "value": "Leaf 3"
    },
    "type": "subtree"
}
```

I could not find how to document those recursive data structures with Spring Restdocs. 
Has anybody some example or could help me.

I have setup a git repo with some code which shows my problem:
https://github.com/dibog/spring-restdocs-recursive-demo

Best regards,
Dieter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you want to document and how you want to describe things to your users. I would focus on the two different types of nodes – subtrees and leafs – and provide documentation that describes their format and that each node in the tree will either be a leaf or a subtree.

You can use REST Docs to document the structure of the two different node types using the response fields snippet, focussed on a specific part of the response:

```
responseFields(beneathPath("left.left").withSubsectionId("leaf"),
    fieldWithPath("id").description("ID of the node"),
    fieldWithPath("type").description("Type of the node. Always 'leaf' for leaf nodes"),
    fieldWithPath("value").description("Value of the node")),
responseFields(beneathPath("left").withSubsectionId("subtree"),
    fieldWithPath("id").description("ID of the node"),
    fieldWithPath("type").description("Type of the node. Always 'subtree' for nodes with children"),
    subsectionWithPath("left").description("Left-hand child node. Either a subtree or a leaf"),
    subsectionWithPath("right").description("Right-hand child node. Either a subtree or a leaf"))
```

The use of `subsectionWithPath` when documenting a subtree node allows you to cover the entire subtree with a single descriptor. The description informs the user that the value of `left` and `right` will be a node that is either a leaf or another subtree.

Comment: Hi Andy, 

thanks for your explanation and code sample. I think I roughly understand your tipp. You document the separate nodes. 

But I'm not sure how to add your fragments to the test case. I tried to add them to my test case, but I fails with exactly the same error messages as before.